# python3 failed to import riak

Tags: python-3.x, riak

I used python 3.9.13, and have installed riak client lib. But I failed to

```
import riak
```

Here's the exception message below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/riak/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from riak.client import RiakClient
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/riak/client/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from riak.client.operations import RiakClientOperations
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/riak/client/operations.py", line 5, in <module>
    from riak.client.transport import RiakClientTransport, \
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/riak/client/transport.py", line 3, in <module>
    from riak.transports.tcp import is_retryable as is_tcp_retryable
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/riak/transports/tcp/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from riak.transports.tcp.transport import TcpTransport
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/riak/transports/tcp/transport.py", line 6, in <module>
    from riak.codecs import Codec, Msg
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/riak/codecs/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    Msg = collections.namedtuple('Msg',
TypeError: namedtuple() got an unexpected keyword argument 'verbose'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `verbose` keyword argument for `namedtuple()` was deprecated in [Python 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields) and it doesn't look like the package version for `riak` on PyPi has been updated to account for this.

It has been patched on the [`master`](https://github.com/basho/riak-python-client/commit/648f9056d47332df890232e85d497623608e2964) branch of the [`riak`](https://github.com/basho/riak-python-client) GitHub repo so you should try pip installing the package directly from GitHub rather from PyPi.

e.g.

```
$ pip install git+https://github.com/basho/riak-python-client
```

Answer (score 1):

And I quote

> You must use version 2.7.11, 3.4.4 or 3.5.1 (or greater within a version series). Otherwise you will be affected by this python bug

Link for the know [bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue23517)

The solution as suggested is to use 3.5.X.

More information can be found at [pypi riak](https://pypi.org/project/riak/) page.

Comment: Thank you! I reinstall riak client manually, and it works.

Comment: yes, If you are restricted to the version Sparrow0hawk works amazingly for you.